Unable to Download File from Remote Server on IIS but Works on Localhost
I am developing a web application in C# that downloads files from a different file server using network credentials. This functionality works perfectly when running on localhost, but when deployed to IIS, the download fails with a "Site can't be reached" message.
Problem:
When attempting to download a file from the remote server on IIS, I receive a "Site can't be reached" message. No error logs are generated, and there are no unusual entries in the Event Viewer. The upload functionality from IIS works as expected.
C#
public HttpResponseMessage DownloadFile(string networkPath, string documentFullPath, NetworkCredential credentials, string documentPath, string contentType)
{
    FileStream stream;
    if (isServer.ToLower() == "true")
    {
        logger.Error("ClinicalEventControll:4710");
        using (new ConnectToSharedFolder(networkPath, credentials))
        {
            logger.Error(":4712");
            stream = new FileStream(networkPath + @"\" + documentFullPath, FileMode.Open);
            httpResponseMessage.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
            httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
            httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = documentPath;
            httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(contentType);
            httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentLength = stream.Length;
        }
    }
    return httpResponseMessage;
}

Network Connection Class:
public class ConnectToSharedFolder : IDisposable
{
    private readonly string _networkName;
    private static readonly ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(ClinicalEventdetailsApiController));
    
    public ConnectToSharedFolder(string networkName, NetworkCredential credentials)
    {
        _networkName = networkName;
        var netResource = new NetResource
        {
            Scope = ResourceScope.GlobalNetwork,
            ResourceType = ResourceType.Disk,
            DisplayType = ResourceDisplaytype.Share,
            RemoteName = networkName
        };

        var userName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(credentials.Domain) ? credentials.UserName : $@"{credentials.Domain}\{credentials.UserName}";

        var result = WNetAddConnection2(netResource, credentials.Password, userName, 0);
        if (result != 0)
        {
            logger.Error(result + " UNC path error status code");
            throw new Win32Exception(result, "Error connecting to remote share");
        }
    }

    ~ConnectToSharedFolder()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        WNetCancelConnection2(_networkName, 0, true);
    }

    [DllImport("mpr.dll")]
    private static extern int WNetAddConnection2(NetResource netResource, string password, string username, int flags);

    [DllImport("mpr.dll")]
    private static extern int WNetCancelConnection2(string name, int flags, bool force);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public class NetResource
    {
        public ResourceScope Scope;
        public ResourceType ResourceType;
        public ResourceDisplaytype DisplayType;
        public int Usage;
        public string LocalName;
        public string RemoteName;
        public string Comment;
        public string Provider;
    }

    public enum ResourceScope : int
    {
        Connected = 1,
        GlobalNetwork,
        Remembered,
        Recent,
        Context
    };

    public enum ResourceType : int
    {
        Any = 0,
        Disk = 1,
        Print = 2,
        Reserved = 8,
    }

    public enum ResourceDisplaytype : int
    {
        Generic = 0x0,
        Domain = 0x01,
        Server = 0x02,
        Share = 0x03,
        File = 0x04,
        Group = 0x05,
        Network = 0x06,
        Root = 0x07,
        Shareadmin = 0x08,
        Directory = 0x09,
        Tree = 0x0a,
        Ndscontainer = 0x0b
    }
}

JavaScript:
function downloadSourceDoc(sourceDocID) {
    showLoader();
    var form = $('form');
    form.attr('action', '../DownloadSourceDoc?SourceDocID=' + sourceDocID + '&RoleID=' + $('#hdnUserRoleID').val());
    form.attr('method', 'POST');
    form.submit();
    closeLoader();
}

Attempts:

I have checked the following:
Network credentials are correct.
The path is accessible from the server.
Necessary permissions are granted.
No error logs are generated.
Event Viewer does not show any unusual entries.

Additional Information:

The upload functionality works from IIS.
Download works from localhost but fails from IIS.


Your code runs differently under IIS, https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3 So mapped drives are most likely to be the cause, and you might switch to UNC path.

Ensure that the file and directory you are trying to download from have the appropriate permissions: ensure that the IIS_IUSRS group has read permissions on the directory and the file and check if the file is not being blocked by any NTFS permissions.
